# Ubuntu 17.10 no scanner device

Tags: scanner

My Ubuntu 17.10 32 bit cannot find the scanners
I also have the 64 bit version on another computer that does work for the same printer/scanner Brother MFC-7460DN
The scanner first worked after the upgrade to 17.10 in which I was sure not change the configuration on the upgrade.
Help apprciated

Comment: There is no 32-bit version of Ubuntu Desktop 17.10. Are you trying it with Ubuntu **Server**? Please [edit] your question and specify the version correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What I experienced when upgrading from 16.4 to 17.10 was that during the update the question was asked whether to retain the 'sane'config script or start anew.
On one update I said no and started anew, the scanner did not work. 
On another update I said yes keep the 'sane' config and it worked the scanner was ok.